# Extracting Latitude and Longitude Coordinates from PBF Files

Tags: qgis, pbf

I aim to retrieve and handle PBF files sourced from an online map. The provided link exemplifies a PBF file:
https://tiles.raah.ir/tiles/low/16/42122/25807.pbf
Upon loading this file into QGIS, the resulting display resembles the image depicted below:
[image]

I desire the latitude and longitude coordinates for these points. The challenge lies in the absence of information regarding the latitude and longitude coordinates within the data contained in this PBF file.

Comment: Coordinates are encoded as per the MVT specification - simplified and coerced into tile space coordinates - and can be read out with respective decoding. QGIS does that for you and coordinates are not available through accessing the geometries.

Comment: you probably want to download the data in some other format

Comment: In QGIS>Vector>Geometry Tools>Centroids will create a new layer with coordinates as attributes.